# Version control using database tables, or source control tool?

Tags: database, ms-access, version-control

Our application has an MS Access 2010 database (I know.. I would much prefer SQL Server, but that's another topic).

Since MS Access stores its data in single mysterious monolithic binary files rather than scripts, my team is thinking of creating several extra tables corresponding to different versions of the software and maintain these versions inside one master database.

I suggest simply placing the binary file in the same source control tool as the software source code.  Then the vast majority of the database content would be a duplicate of the other versions, but at least it puts the version control tool in control of the software source and database simultaneously in a synced fashion.

The application uses XML files that are exported from the database (doesn't tie into the database directly).

What are the pros and cons of these two approaches?

I'm familiar with version control methods for SQL Server, but MS Access seems cumbersome to manage for applications with lots of branches.

Answer (score 0):

To put it short: You are pushing Access to something it is not intended for.

You do have the commands `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText` that can export and import most objects as discrete text files. This has been used by *Visual SourceSafe* to create some sort of source control but it doesn't work 100% reliably.

Also, you can just as well import and export objects "as is" to another (archive) database building some kind of version control.

I once worked with a team in a very large corporation having all imaginable resources from MS at hand and, still, we ended up with a simple system of zip files given a filename including the date and time.

We had a master *accdb* file we pulled as a copy to a local folder, then did what we were assigned, and copied the file back leaving a note about what objects were altered. One person had the task to collect the altered objects and "rebuild" a new master. A minimum was one per day, but often we also created one at lunch break.

It worked better than you might imagine, because we typically operated in different corners - one with some reports, one with other reports, one with some forms, and one (typically me) with some code modules. Of course, mistakes happened, but as we had the zip files, it was always fast and safe to pull an old copy of an object if in doubt.